# What does PIL's convert method exactly do with palette = Image.adaptive in python?

Tags: python, image, colors, python-imaging-library, palette

I used PIL library to write in python a prototype of the kmeans algorithm applied on an image.
As initial centroids I used the first k colors that

```
convert('P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=N_CLUSTERS)
```

extracts . I've already read convert's source code (in image.py) but I haven't understood how it works when I choose the ADAPTIVE choice, which seems to be very effective

My aim is to implement kmeans in C++ so I can't rely on what convert() method does to find the first k centroids, I have to deeply understand its behavior, in order to replicate it in C++.

Thank you

Comment: Why not look at the PIL source code?

Comment: Have you read my question?

Comment: My apologies; don't know how I missed that. If you have already read the source code, maybe ask a question about the specific part(s) you don't understand.

Comment: ok thank you. I haven't understood what happens in quantize() method. I can't find where the palette creation has place.